# Nautilus stops working in 14.04

Tags: nautilus

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Sometimes when I start my computer , it shows

> System Error , Natilus Stops Working.

And while I typed `sudo nautilus` from terminal, it shows

```
(nautilus:4260): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
```

Is this may be a problem? If so, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal window and copy/paste these commands, one by one:

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus  
sudo apt-get install nautilus  
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Answer (score -1):

Nautilus is looking for samba which seams that it is not installed

Install samba

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```